# Caused by: net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: no such column: rp.Active: на Android 9

Tags: android, sqlite

Есть метод:

```
public Cursor getListResearchPanel() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(Models.KEY);
    String query = "select rp._id, rp.Name, count(sa._id)  from ResearchPanels as rp " +
            "left join ResearchPanelRelations as RPR on rp._id = RPR.IdPanel " +
            "left join sp_analiz as sa on RPR.IdResearch = sa._id " +
            "where rp.Active=1 " +
            "group by rp.Name " +
            "order by rp.Name";
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
```

Данный метод работает на Android 5 но не хочет работать на 9ке.
Логкат показывает что не может найти столбец Active хотя в базе есть.

Вот полный стек ошибки:

```
2019-04-20 17:24:43.999 11441-11441/com.example.rp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rp, PID: 11441
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rp/com.example.rp.MainActivity}: net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: no such column: rp.Active: , while compiling: select rp._id, rp.Name, count(sa._id)  from ResearchPanels as rp left join ResearchPanelRelations as RPR on rp._id = RPR.IdPanel left join sp_analiz as sa on RPR.IdResearch = sa._id where rp.Active=1 group by rp.Name order by rp.Name
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2916)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3051)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1811)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6694)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: no such column: rp.Active: , while compiling: select rp._id, rp.Name, count(sa._id)  from ResearchPanels as rp left join ResearchPanelRelations as RPR on rp._id = RPR.IdPanel left join sp_analiz as sa on RPR.IdResearch = sa._id where rp.Active=1 group by rp.Name order by rp.Name
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:89)
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:48)
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:60)
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:2012)
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1898)
    at com.example.rp.data.DbHelper.getListResearchPanel(DbHelper.java:138)
    at com.example.rp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2896)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3051) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1811) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6694) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Если ошибка говорит что нет столбца значит ее там нет. Проверяй еще раз

Comment: Вполне возможно , чт онадо удалить ручками базу данных или переустановить АПК. Код не читаемый особо поэтому не вникал, хотя бы синтаксис для начала привести в норму

Answer (score 0):

Начну с пары замечаний:

- зачем столько переименований? Как ни странно, краткость не всегда
  сестра таланта. Запрос выглядит совершенно нечитаемым. И эти
  переименования могут быть источником проблемы
- выделяйте поля и
  таблицы обратными апострофами(на клавише с тильдой), в некоторых бд
  есть определенные требования к таким формальностям, и от версии к
  версии они не совпадают. У sqlite таких бзиков вроде не наблюдается,
  но мало ли
- сначала все джойним, потом фильтруем по значению. Плохой
  подход :) сначала ResearchPanels фильтруем по значению Active, что
  осталось джойним

Я бы предположил что проблема как раз в переименованиях. Поставь брейкпоинт на ретерне, убери из запроса фильтрацию по Active и запусти. Когда программа остановится на брейкпоинте в наблюдениях получи от курсора список полей. Не сильно удивлюсь если поле зовется Active, а не rp.Active. Причем если я прав, то будет ругаться и на rp.Name

Comment: Согласен, принимаю вашу критику, на будущее лучше сделать так как вы написали. Но как ни странно проблема была в том что действительно Андроид 9 не видел данное поле хотя в базе он присутствовал. Чего только не делал: начиная от удаление приложения до пересборки проекта. Данное поле появилась после того как я создал еще одно поле которое просто называется Field4 в этой же таблице. Хочу отметить что после добавления поля я не менял сам скрипт в коде.

Comment: Тогда поздравляю с боевым крещением, иногда магия случается :) Мне хочется предположить что-нибудь на тему "подвисшего" журнала или еще чего, но я упорно не могу представить как создание одного поля могло ткнуть драйвер во второе пальцем... Тут, боюсь, высока вероятность что никто никогда не поймет, что произошло